# Doctrine Pager and Group By

Tags: doctrine, paging

I'm having an issue with Doctrine's pager when the original query has a GROUP BY. The pager will generate this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM event e GROUP BY e.type
```

which is not correct as the original query should be encapsulated in parenthesis. It should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * AS num_results FROM event e GROUP BY e.type)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$table->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_LIMIT, Doctrine_Core::LIMIT_ROWS);
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en